# Is it possible to start cassandra opscenter with a pre-configured node by passing it in as a startup parameter?

Tags: docker, parameters, cassandra, consul, opscenter

When you start Cassandra OpsCentre - you have to [add the nodes manually](https://www.prado.it/2012/05/04/how-to-run-apache-cassandra-database-on-a-two-nodes-ubuntu-12-04-lts-cluster/) in the GUI:

[image]

Now I'm aware you can add [address information](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/agentAddressConfiguration.html) in the `address.yml` file.

In a service discovery environment (eg [Consul](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/consul.html) and [docker](https://www.docker.com/)) - you want to script the opscenter to come up, but be able to parameterise the nodes as a start-up parameter from the output of the service discovery.

My question is: **Is it possible to start cassandra opscenter with a pre-configured node by passing it in as a startup parameter?**

Answer (score 0):

In OpsCenter, Check a file called  cluster_name.conf where you can configure the cluster hosts. After changing properties in this file, restart OpsCenter for the changes to take effect.

```
/etc/opscenter/clusters/cluster_name.conf
```

The alternate option to discover the nodes during startup is auto-discovery,

```
[cassandra]
auto_node_discovery = True
```

Further, if you are adding the nodes manually in a large cluster, It's suggested to off the auto-node-discoery and increase the node list poll period.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/examples/opscConfiguringForVeryLargeClusters.html

Answer (score 0):

OpsCenter developer here. The OpsCenter UI is "just" a client of the OpsCenter api. The create-cluster endpoint is is documented at https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/api/docs/opscenter_config.html#method-add-cluster-config.

As a general strategy, I recommend that instead of looking for filesystem modifications you can make or startup parameters you can pass, that you wrap OpsCenter startup in a script that blocks until the API is available and then issues API requests to perform whatever change you desire. For any given goal, there may be a way to achieve it with startup-params or by manipulated on-disk state, but if you use the API you'll be set up to do everything OpsCenter can do. I realize that's probably not an idiomatic way to do things on your platform, but it's going to be the most flexible way to interact with OpsCenter.

Comment: You're saying to curl some hosts in and then try

Comment: I'm not sure what "curl some hosts in and then try" means. The screenshot in your question is the form that you see when adding a cluster to OpsCenter to be monitored. The result of that form is an API call, which is documented at the link in my answer. To automate that process, start OpsCenter, wait for the api to become responsive by polling some endpoint that responds to GET, and then submit the POST request required to add your desired cluster. This is not a "startup parameter" to OpsCenter, but allows you to achieve your goal through a different mechanism that can be reliably automated.